Constructed Sentence Coherency
I've been teaching myself bits and pieces of Latin from Wiktionary and a few other free resources. I like to try and translate interesting concepts (in English) into comparatively concise Latin, similar to the widely used 'Latin motto'. Thus I've been pointed here a few times as a great place to get feedback and check one's work.
My question: how would you translate the following into English?
Nihil nos imperat
hinc fugit(ur) nemo vivens
Thanks in advance for your time :) Suggestions for free Latin learning resources also very appreciated.

Duolingo has a Latin course. It's not great but it can be helpful as one of the resources.

Also take a look at our Latin self-study question.

If you tell us what do you think they mean/want them to mean, we can try to help you improve your translations. I don't think questions of the 'Try to guess what English phrase I'm trying to render into Latin based on a very limited knowledge of the language' type are terribly constructive.

@cnread The first sentence started as "no one tells us what to do/nothing rules us" or something to that effect. I liked the idea of nil vs nemo here as I thought it was broader (i.e. no person nor thing vs no person). The second is a phrase I saw in a book recently: 'no one gets out of here alive'. Thanks for your help!
